# mariabackup crashing, help

Tags: backup, mariadb

Hi I'm using mariabackup on one of my **MariaDB 10.5.4** nodes from my **Galera Cluster** and whenever I run it i get this from my output logs:

```
[00] 2020-08-05 11:26:40 Connecting to MySQL server host: localhost, user: mariabackup, password: set, port: 3306, socket: /mdb/mysql-data/mysql.sock
[00] 2020-08-05 11:26:40 Using server version 10.5.4-MariaDB-log
mariabackup based on MariaDB server 10.5.4-MariaDB Linux (x86_64)
[00] 2020-08-05 11:26:40 uses posix_fadvise().
[00] 2020-08-05 11:26:40 cd to /mdb/mysql-data/
[00] 2020-08-05 11:26:40 open files limit requested 0, set to 1024
[00] 2020-08-05 11:26:40 mariabackup: using the following InnoDB configuration:
[00] 2020-08-05 11:26:40 innodb_data_home_dir =
[00] 2020-08-05 11:26:40 innodb_data_file_path = ibdata1:12M:autoextend
[00] 2020-08-05 11:26:40 innodb_log_group_home_dir = ./
[00] 2020-08-05 11:26:40 InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
2020-08-05 11:26:40 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
[00] 2020-08-05 11:26:40 mariabackup: Generating a list of tablespaces
2020-08-05 11:26:40 0 [Warning] InnoDB: Allocated tablespace ID 1 for mysql/innodb_table_stats, old maximum was 0
2020-08-05 11:26:41 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Operating system error number 24 in a file operation.
2020-08-05 11:26:41 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Error number 24 means 'Too many open files'
2020-08-05 11:26:41 0 [Note] InnoDB: Some operating system error numbers are described at https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/operating-system-error-codes/
2020-08-05 11:26:41 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: File ./glpi_dev/glpi_plugin_formcreator_targettickets.ibd: 'open' returned OS error 224.
2020-08-05 11:26:41 0x7f034b892980  InnoDB: Assertion failure in file /home/buildbot/buildbot/padding_for_CPACK_RPM_BUILD_SOURCE_DIRS_PREFIX/mariadb-10.5.4/storage/innobase/fil/fil0fil.cc line 497
InnoDB: Failing assertion: success
InnoDB: We intentionally generate a memory trap.
InnoDB: Submit a detailed bug report to https://jira.mariadb.org/
InnoDB: If you get repeated assertion failures or crashes, even
InnoDB: immediately after the mysqld startup, there may be
InnoDB: corruption in the InnoDB tablespace. Please refer to
InnoDB: https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/innodb-recovery-modes/
InnoDB: about forcing recovery.
200805 11:26:41 [ERROR] mysqld got signal 6 ;
This could be because you hit a bug. It is also possible that this binary
or one of the libraries it was linked against is corrupt, improperly built,
or misconfigured. This error can also be caused by malfunctioning hardware.

To report this bug, see https://mariadb.com/kb/en/reporting-bugs

We will try our best to scrape up some info that will hopefully help
diagnose the problem, but since we have already crashed,
something is definitely wrong and this may fail.

Server version: 10.5.4-MariaDB
key_buffer_size=0
read_buffer_size=131072
max_used_connections=0
max_threads=1
thread_count=0
It is possible that mysqld could use up to
key_buffer_size + (read_buffer_size + sort_buffer_size)*max_threads = 5978 K  bytes of memory
Hope that's ok; if not, decrease some variables in the equation.

Thread pointer: 0x0
Attempting backtrace. You can use the following information to find out
where mysqld died. If you see no messages after this, something went
terribly wrong...
stack_bottom = 0x0 thread_stack 0x49000
Can't start addr2line
mariabackup(my_print_stacktrace+0x2e)[0x55b875e6050e]
mariabackup(handle_fatal_signal+0x485)[0x55b875955895]
/lib64/libpthread.so.0(+0x12dd0)[0x7f034b47cdd0]
/lib64/libc.so.6(gsignal+0x10f)[0x7f034921b70f]
/lib64/libc.so.6(abort+0x127)[0x7f0349205b25]
mariabackup(+0x647ad1)[0x55b8755baad1]
mariabackup(+0x613b1f)[0x55b875586b1f]
mariabackup(+0xc7540f)[0x55b875be840f]
mariabackup(+0x696711)[0x55b875609711]
mariabackup(+0x6957c0)[0x55b8756087c0]
mariabackup(+0x695c3f)[0x55b875608c3f]
mariabackup(+0x698842)[0x55b87560b842]
mariabackup(main+0x177)[0x55b8755ca487]
/lib64/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xf3)[0x7f03492076a3]
mariabackup(_start+0x2e)[0x55b87560473e]
The manual page at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql/en/crashing.html contains
information that should help you find out what is causing the crash.
Writing a core file...
Working directory at /mdb/mysql-data
completed in 1 seconds
```

Here's my my.cnf configuration:

```
[client-server]
port=3306
socket=/mdb/mysql-data/mysql.sock

[mysqld]
datadir=/mdb/mysql-data
socket=/mdb/mysql-data/mysql.sock

proxy-protocol-networks=10.10.10.15, 10.10.10.18

wsrep_slave_threads=2
innodb_lock_wait_timeout=8000
innodb_io_capacity=2000
innodb_buffer_pool_size=5G
innodb_buffer_pool_instances=5
innodb_log_buffer_size=256M
innodb_log_file_size=1G
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit=2
```

I have **8GB RAM** and **Dual-core CPU**.

Comment: Additional information request. 
Any SSD or NVME devices on MySQL Host server? 
Post on pastebin.com and share the links. 
From your SSH login root, Text results of: 
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.

Comment: Now that you are no longer crashing, would you like to reduce time to complete queries?  If you, please post additional information requested Aug 6 at 13:23. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Increasing Open File Descriptors & Process Limits fixed it. Followed the instructions from [this website](https://coding-stream-of-consciousness.com/2018/12/21/centos7-and-rhel7-increasing-open-file-descriptors-process-limits/).

Comment: the crash is unnecessary and probably detected from the fix you put here. There's a bug to fix this hopefully [MDEV-18200](https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-18200)